# How to duplicate an entire column with values with Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a column in a table of +15000 entries - I want to duplicate that entire column while retaining it's values and name it differently. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

How do I go about that?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to rename the column or you want to end up with two columns?

Comment: Sorry, should of been clearer.
Want to end up with two columns different names same values.

Comment: @Alex: I've got to know; why would you want two different columns with the same values?

Comment: The new duplicated column (B) will contain 25 different values coming from column (A) to start off with.


The idea is to maintain the 25 different values for Column A and find and replace Column B values down to 10.

There are over +15000 entries and I figured that was the easiest way to approach this.

Comment: @Alex: I've posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842194/how-to-duplicate-an-entire-column-with-values-with-microsoft-sql-server/3842464#3842464) that I think will solve this for you without the need to copy data first.

Comment: Simply, because we are waiting on the client ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments to the original question, I understand that you are trying to preserve 25 distinct values in ColumnA while converting the new ColumnB to hold 10 different values. I think you could do something like the code below. Modify my datatypes to match your situation.

```
declare @ColumnAConverter table (
    ColumnA nvarchar(max), 
    ColumnB nvarchar(max)
)

insert into @ColumnAConverter
    (ColumnA, ColumnB)
    select 'A', '1'
    union all
    select 'B', '1'
    union all
    select 'C', '2'
    /* ...continue for all 25 values in the original ColumnA */

update yt
    set ColumnB = c.ColumnB
    from YourTable yt
        inner join @ColumnAConverter c
            on yt.ColumnA = c.ColumnA
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joe - I will definitely give this a shot :)

Answer (score 4):

Create a new column and then

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET NewColumn = OldColumn
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE Boo
Add [NewColumnName] [datetype]
GO

Update Boo
Set NewColumnName = OldColumn
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not a computed column?

```
ALTER TABLE Foo ADD NewColumnName AS OldColumnName
```

This alos applies of you want to change a number into text for example

```
ALTER TABLE Foo ADD NewColumnName AS RIGHT('ABC000000' + CAST(OldColumnName AS varchar(10)), 10)

1       ABC0000001
2       ABC0000002
3       ABC0000003
4       ABC0000004
5       ABC0000005
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT into tbl (colname,fld1,fld2,fld3,fld4)  
 SELECT 'NEWNAME' as colname, fld1,fld2,fld3,fld4  
 FROM tbl where uniqid=[SOMEVAL]
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question; this doesn't call for inserting new records.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

   ALTER TABLE myTable
       Add newcol NVARCHAR(8)
   GO 

   UPDATE myTable
       Set newcol = oldcol
   GO 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Replace NVARCHAR(8) with whatever you current columns data type is.